# Azure devops test task: how to display messages during Visual Studio test execution

Tags: .net, unit-testing, azure-devops

I have some unit tests which can take several time to complete the execution.
In these I added some messages to show the unit test progress, using `Console.WriteLine`.

In my pipeline, during the "Visual Studio Test" task these messages aren't shown. I'd like to see them during the test execution, through the details log view.

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible for the console logs. If you use the Visual Studio Test task to run tests, diagnostic output logged from tests (using any of Console.WriteLine, Trace.WriteLine or TestContext.WriteLine methods), will appear as an **attachment** for a **failed** test.

[image]

However, a full test run output is available in the `trx` file found in the test run. If you open the `trx` file from the Notepad, you will see there is an `Output` element for each test:

[image]

```
 <UnitTestResult executionId="xxx" testId="xxx" testName="M2Test" computerName="xxxx" duration="00:00:00.0001844" startTime="2021-01-14T08:10:11.5942741+00:00" endTime="2021-01-14T08:10:11.5962978+00:00" testType="13cdc9d9-xxxx" outcome="Passed" testListId="8cxxxx" relativeResultsDirectory="504xxxxx">
      <Output>
        <StdOut>cecehi</StdOut>
      </Output>
    </UnitTestResult>
```

Comment: Ok, but I can see the attachments only when test execution completes. Is there a way to see the messages during the test execution?

Comment: Unfortunately, we can not see the diagnostic output during the test execution.

Comment: Ok, thank you anyway. At least now I know it is not possible :D